# C++ cast pointer to static method

Tags: c++, methods, static, compiler-errors, interrupt

I haven't write C++ code in a long while; however now I have to work on a texas instruments F28335 DSP and I am trying to migrate from C to C++.
I have the following code that is trying to initialize an interrupt service routine with a static method of a class:

```
//type definition for the interrupt service routine
typedef interrupt void (*PINT)(void);
//EPWMManager.h
class EPWMManager
{
public:
    EPWMManager();      
    static interrupt void Epwm1InterruptHandler(void);  
};
//EPWMManager.cpp
interrupt void EPWMManager::Epwm1InterruptHandler(void)
{
 //some code to be called on interruption
}   
//main.cpp
int main(void)
{
    PINT p;
    p = &(EPWMManager::Epwm1InterruptHandler);
    return 0;
 }
```

When compiling I get the following:

> error: a value of type "void (*)()" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "PINT"

I guess I'm missing some cast.

Comment: The `interrupt` keyword is not a part of C++. It must be an extension specific to your implementation. What happens if you remove it from the definitions of both `PINT` and `Epwm1InterruptHandler`? Do you still get an error?

Comment: In my experience quality of TI compilers for DSP processors is not impressive even for C (e.g. we bounced more than once in bugs of the code generator on boundary cases of page handling). Are you sure that migrating to a much more complex language like C++ is a good idea?

Comment: if i take 'interrupt' out the error is out... However I am not sure of the implications it has. I was thinking that migrating to C++ would be a good idea in order to have everything more structured (classes, objects, design patterns, etc) since our C code is starting to look very messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fundamental problem is that ampersand prefixing the RHS of your assignment to p.  Also, "PINT" is "pointer to integer" in other operating systems.  So let's avoid any potential name conflicts.  But I thinks this will work for you:

```
// you may have to move "interrupt" keyword to the left of the "void" declaration.  Or just remove it.
typedef void (interrupt *FN_INTERRUPT_HANDLER)(void);

interrupt void EPWMManager::Epwm1InterruptHandler(void)
{
 //some code to be called on interruption
}  

int main(void)
{
    FN_INTERRUPT_HANDLER p;
    p = EPWMManager::Epwm1InterruptHandler; // no ampersand

    // and if for whatever reason you wanted to invoke your function, you could just do this:

   p(); // this will invoke your function.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right. The provided code works just fine. After a closer look at my code I observed that the typedef was declared as external C, making it incompatible with the C++ code. I removed that, and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several unrelated syntax mistakes here: as I understand your Epwm1InterruptHandler is supposed to return a pointer to a function of type interrupt, then first remove void from line

```
static interrupt void Epwm1InterruptHandler(void);
```

and

```
static interrupt void Epwm1InterruptHandler(void);
```

then make p of type interrupt, and then put brackets like this:

```
interrupt p;
p = &(EPWMManager::Epwm1InterruptHandler());
```

Comment: That function *IS* the interrupt handler, not something that returns a pointer to an interrupt handler.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing a ; after typedef interrupt void (*PINT)(void)?
Your code compiles for me.